# Image transitions in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage

I'm exploring what transitions/effects are available for image switching. Main idea was to use 2 UIImageView and switch views using built-in iOS animations:

- Flip views
- Curl
- swing
- fade in/out
- zoom in/out

is there other effects i can use in my slideshow? BTW, I'm not gonna use paging control. Will it be easier to work with UIImage on a single UIImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a full list of the animations available please look at the UIViewAnimationOptions type definition:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions

Comment: yeah, thanks, I've seen that. I would be more interested in using UIImage directly...if that's possible and easy enough to implement.

Comment: No I do not believe you cannot animate a UIImage directly. UIImageView can take advantage of the UIView animation mechanisms, and is *much* easier than doing layer animations directly.